# How to get Inno Setup to use the data folder from a different install?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an Inno Setup installer for my Windows app which saves the data folder (edited by the user during the install) in two places:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ChessOpeningsWizardProfessional2016_is1`

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-253778795-1228266984-3707684546-1000\Software\Bookup\Chess Openings Wizard Professional 2016\Installer Settings`

How do I write a new different separate installer that just installs a sample document for this app - and autofills the data folder that the user chose when installing the app?

Put another way, how do I get...

```pascal
DataDirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('ChessOpeningsWizard2016DataDir', '');
```

...to fetch the value from one of those registry keys above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the same [`AppId`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) for both installers, as the other installer is kind of an update of the main package.

And you may want to combine that with [`UpdateUninstallLogAppName=no`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_updateuninstalllogappname) to keep name of the main package in the *"Add or remove programs"* control panel.

---

Or just use registry functions like [`RegQueryStringValue`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue).

Comment: The ebook can be installed for programs using different AppId's.

RegQueryStringValue did the trick though. Thanks!